# Can't remove Null terminator from byte array?

Tags: go

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/elliottsam/winrm-dns-client) in Go (on OSX) to interact with a windows DNS server.

When running the below snippet, I get an error about a null terminator.

```
 $ ~/go/bin/winrm-dns-client create -d domain.com -n node-0 -t A -v 10.90.61.30
2018/06/03 12:40:22 Error creating DNS record: Reading record: Reading record: Unmarshalling response: Unmarshalling json: invalid character '\x00' after array element
```

My suspicion is that there's a null terminator added [here](https://github.com/elliottsam/winrm-dns-client/blob/master/dns/helpers.go#L69) when the helper method calls `sprintf` to concat json responses into an array.

However, even after adding a `bytes.Trim` like shown below... I still get a null terminator error and it seems that the null terminator still exists...

```
func unmarshalResponse(resp string) ([]interface{}, error) {
    var data interface{}
    byteRespTrim := []byte(resp)
    fmt.Print("found a null terminator at -- ")
    fmt.Println(bytes.Index(byteRespTrim, []byte("\x00")))
    fmt.Print("total length = ")
    fmt.Println(len(byteRespTrim))
    byteRespTrim = bytes.Trim(byteRespTrim, "\x00")
    fmt.Print("after trim found a null terminator at -- ")
    loc := bytes.Index(byteRespTrim, []byte("\x00"))
    fmt.Print(loc)
```

When calling I get the below

```
(master)⚡ % ./windows-dns-test create -d domain.com -n openshift-node-0 -t A -v 10.90.61.30                       
found a null terminator at -- 2102
total length = 2615
after trim found a null terminator at -- 2102
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logs, the offending character seems to be found at position `2102`, while the whole array has `2615` elements.

So it looks `Trim` won't solve it since the problem is not necessarily the final character of the array.

Did you try removing all occurrences, using `Replace` for example?

```
byteRespTrim = bytes.Replace(byteRespTrim, []byte("\x00"), []byte{}, -1)
```